# Which would you use for an almost sorted file, Insertion or Selection Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm wondering whether you would use insertion or selection for an almost sorted file.  How many swaps do both of them do on average? I have heard both `N/2` and `O(n)` used for selection! I know with insertion you must scan the sorted section of the array to find where to put the new element but in the selection, you must scan the entire unsorted part of the array to find the next element to add to the beginning of the unsorted subarray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of popular sort algorithms that are designed to take advantage of almost-sorted data. Probably the most popular is [timsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), named after Tim Peters, a Python core developer who first proposed and implemented the algorithm as the default sort algorithm used in Python. The sort algorithm is now also used as the default sorting algorithm in many versions of Java.

> Timsort is a hybrid stable sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data. [...] The algorithm finds subsequences of the data that are already ordered, and uses that knowledge to sort the remainder more efficiently. This is done by merging an identified subsequence, called a run, with existing runs until certain criteria are fulfilled. [...] [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

---

Insertion sort is quite efficient when data is almost sorted in the sense that it is approximately sorted:

> the time complexity is O(nk) when each element in the input is no more than k places away from its sorted position [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Insertion sort cannot take advantage of many other common cases where the data is almost sorted, such as reversed order or when the data is composed of two runs of sorted data (e.g. from the result of concatenating two sorted arrays).

Selection sort doesn't really benefit from almost sorted data. So it's a poor choice of algorithm if you do know that your data have some near ordering in it.

Answer (score 1):

In the comparison of selection and insertion sort, selection sort works in `\Theta(n^2)` and compare all values in the list. Hence, the near sorting of the array does not help to sort faster in selection sort! However, in insertion sort the worst-case is in `O(n^2)` and for nearly sorted arrays, changing the unsorted parts of the array and will have better performance than selection sort in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In Insertion sort, for worst case senario О(n^2) comparisons and swaps, for best case O(n) comparisons, O(1) swaps.

In selection sort, the sorted and unsorted array doesn’t make any difference and consumes an order of n2 (O(n2)) in both best and worst case complexity.

So for you case of almost sorted file, insertion sort would be better.